# Unable to find browser js code for nodejs crypto code

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I have a nodejs code which generate signature based on current time stamp:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nonce = new Date().getTime();
var signature = function(nonce, secretKey) {
    var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(secretKey, 'utf8')).update(Buffer.from(nonce, 'utf8')).digest('base64');
    return signature;
}
```

I am converting this code into browser js but i did not succeed in my task.
I took reference from this link: [nodejs crypto module vs crypto-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855120/nodejs-crypto-module-vs-crypto-js)
but did not work.

if `nonce=1518440585425` and `secret=9IeVABv94EQBnT6Mn73742kBZOmzFpsM+c62LU9b/h4=` it should give this `signature=blI2ILR8MW4ParkT4R1vvVOXF42gJOAVPgEJtZT7Ivo=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nodejs` signature generation code will be equivalent to this `crypto js` code:

```
var secret="9IeVABv94EQBnT6Mn73742kBZOmzFpsM+c62LU9b/h4=";
var nonce = "1518440585425";
var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,secret);
hmac.update(nonce);
var hash = hmac.finalize();
var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

console.log(signature); //blI2ILR8MW4ParkT4R1vvVOXF42gJOAVPgEJtZT7Ivo
```

You will need to include these js in your HTML file:

```
<script src="components/core.js"></script>
<script src="components/hmac.js"></script>
<script src="components/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="components/enc-base64.js"></script>
```